# Passing arguments to singletons in python

Tags: python, singleton

I'm using the following code to instantiate a singleton in python:

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dic):
        super(Singleton, cls).__init__(name, bases, dic)
        cls.instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.instance is None:
            if DEBUG:
                print("Creating NEW Orchestrator instance")
        else:
            if DEBUG:
                print("Using EXISTING Orchestrator instance")

            cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

        return cls.instance
```

The **init** looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, arg=None):
    ...
```

When I instantiate the object it doesn't seem to accept the argument:

```
Obj = Object("parameter")
```

arg does not equal `"parameter"`. It is None.

I thought this was the purpose in passing *args to the **call**.
How would I pass an argument upon first instantiating a singleton?

Comment: Please include the full definition for your `Object` class.  I am assuming this is using `Singleton` as its metaclass?

Comment: Don't you usually do this stuff in `__new__`, not `__init__`?

Comment: (Trivial note) It looks like there currently is a formatting / indentation issue inside your `__call__` method -- the first else statement and its block should probably be "outdented" one level.

Comment: `if debug: ... else: if debug: ...` - what?

Comment: Surely if a singleton contructor takes arguments, it's not a singleton...

Comment: @Eric: Well, it uses arguments from the first constructor call and then ignores arguments for every subsequent constructor call… but that doesn't make it not a singleton, it just makes it a very weird singleton.

Comment: Just in case: usually [a singleton is a bad idea](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/); [a factory is a better one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: FYI: It's a cheap way to maintain state - except when it doesn't work. I intend to refactor it out but currently that's the cheap and easy way to test other functionality. Also, @jedwards actually, I just had one too many if's in there. The else is appropriately part of the second if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current `Singleton` class the following seems to work fine on Python 3.x (which I am assuming you are using based on the `print` function.

```
class Object(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        print("creating instance with arg:", arg)
```

For example:

```
>>> Object("parameter")
creating NEW Orchestrator instance
creating instance with arg: parameter
<__main__.Object object at 0x7f45f9ce8910>
>>> Object("foobar")   # returns the same instance as the above call
<__main__.Object object at 0x7f45f9ce8910>
```

**Edit:** You can do the same sort of thing on Python 2.x, the syntax for specifying the metaclass is just a little bit different:

```
class Object(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        print("creating instance with arg:", arg)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using 3. I prefer the print so I import from __future__.

Comment: See my edit, you can do the same sort of thing on Python 2.x.

Comment: Your edit is how I was originally performing it. Declaring metaclass=None as the default parameter did not work for me. It results in a syntax error on the assignment operator.

Comment: Ok. I just tried it again. It works. I do not know what caused my original error. I'll check my git log to see what else I've changed since then that could have been the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Better use it like this :

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(cls,name,bases,dic):
        super(Singleton,cls).__init__(name,bases,dic)
        cls.instance=None
    def __call__(cls,*args,**kw):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance=super(Singleton,cls).__call__(*args,**kw)
        return cls.instance

class Object(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        print a 

c = Object("parameter")
```

I suppose...

Note: *This works under Python 2.7.4*

Comment: I noted that the above does in fact work however it fails when using a default parameter. That is what I don't understand.

Comment: I changed `def __init__(self, a):` to `def __init__(self, a=None):` and I don't see where it fails. As far as I tested, this behaves as expected.